# Is this function without one-sided limit continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider $$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{0,} &\quad\text{x}\le0\\
       \text{1,} &\quad\text{x}\ge1 \\
     \end{cases}$$

I checked and it seems that this function is indeed continuous! However what still bothers me is that unlike $1/x$ it does not have right-handed limit! (in $x = 0$) And there is a theorem that if two-sided limit exists than also both one-sided exist too. But I guess this theorem does not apply because for it to be applied it is necessary for both one-sided limits to be defined in this point.

Yeah, now that I think of it, one can define a function in only one point, say  $x = 1$, I know that such functions are continuous however both of it one-sided limits are not defined.

Is this correct? (For clarification: I said that limit exists meaning that function converges at this point, limit does not exist = function diverges at this point, limit is defined (or well-defined) iff the point at which it is considered is an adherent point of the usual domain in which the limit is considered, limit is not definied (or ill-defined) iff the point is not an adherent point of the set in which the limit is considered)

Comment: This function isn't defined in $x\in (0,1)$ so it is continuous everywhere except in $[0,1]$

Comment: I was ready for such answer and I'm ready to fight it! The notion of continuity isn't defined outside of a function domain! So this function can not be discontinuous in $x\in (0,1)$ by definition! (It is not continuous, nor discontinuous in those points, the nothion of continuity just not defined there!)I guess the same reasoning applies to "special" zero and one points

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar I know that there are different (a little bit outdated) definitions of continuity out there, requiring for a function to be defined at a point to be able to be continuous at it but in my (i hope modern) definition it is "wrapped" inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Rudin, the definition of continuity is

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $E\subset X, p\in E$, and $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$. Then f is said to be continuous at $p$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$d_Y(f(x), f(p))< \epsilon$$ for all points $x\in E$ for which $d_X(x,p)<\delta$.

By this definition, consider $X$ as $\mathbb{R}$, $E=(-\infty, 0]\cup [1,\infty)$. Then the definition fit. Thus, $f$ is continuous, even at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Isn't $p\in E^\circ$, interior point ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this function is continuous on its domain. It is easy to show that if a sequence (xn) in the domain of f converges to a point x , then f(xn) converges to f(x) therefore the f is continuous on its domain.

Comment: @MRK  does it really makes sense saying that a function is continuous in it's domain because  that's what we actually do , definition of continuity itself says about it

Comment: Since there are functions that are not continuous on their  entire domain, it does make sense to mention that this function is continuous at every point of its domain.

Comment: Exactly @MRK that's what I am saying , Either a function is continuous or it's discontinuous  we don't really mention where , unless asked upon